# strpos in typoscript. Find a needle inside a string

Tags: if-statement, typo3, typoscript

Is there something like strpos in typoscript?

I would like to find a string inside an other string. If the string was found, a COA should appear.

```
site.10 = COA
site.10 {


  stdWrap.if.isTrue
  stdWrap.if.??
}
```

I do not know how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, there is nothing build in that you could use directly with typoscript. But you can build yourself a little helper that does the same.

**Example**

```
# fn.isInString will return true, if the needle was found in string
fn.isInString = COA
fn.isInString {
    1 = LOAD_REGISTER
    1 {
        # REGISTER for what you are looking for
        needle = 

        # REGISTER 
        haystack = 

        # split haystack by the needle
        # result is a haystack without a needle, if found
        findNeedleInHaystack.cObject = TEXT
        findNeedleInHaystack.cObject {
            data = REGISTER:haystack
            split.token.data = REGISTER:needle 
        }
    }

    # compare REGISTER:haystack and result of REGISTER:findNeedleInHaystack
    # if both are the same, nothing was found
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        # true will be returned, if the needle was found inside haystack
        value = true

        if {
            value.data = REGISTER:haystack 
            equals.data = REGISTER:findNeedleInHaystack

            negate = 1
        }
    }
}


# working example
site = PAGE
site {
    10 = COA
    10 {
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = Your content will apear, if the needle was found in the haystack! :O

        stdWrap.if.isTrue.cObject < fn.isInString
        stdWrap.if.isTrue.cObject.1 {
            needle = needle
            haystack = needle in the haystack
        }
    }
}
```

There are many other ways to achive this:

- you could extend stdWrap.if with something that fits you needs
- you could use a UserFunc with strPos-functionality in php

Comment: Crazy, thanks. I didn't know you could do a function in TS! If it goes on like this, I may understand TypoScript one day.

Comment: Np. I do not know, if we can call it function, but it works like a function. fn is no resvered word. We could also call it anArrayFullOfConfigurtaionsWhichActsLikeAFunctionWhenWeUseIt. (: